# why Future<void> don't work properly when we set it as static

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method, when I normally call it without setting it to static, it works fine

But when I declare that future to static like :

```
static Future<main> method() {
 \\... 
 }
```

Ut doesn't work, it throws an error
Why, and what exactly the problem

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: Send some part of code snippit